# Ubuntu Puma Upstart Script fails

Tags: ubuntu, puma

I am able to start Puma using this command:
$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec puma -C /home/deploy/tasks/shared/puma.rb --daemon -p 3000
And the app is working serving all pages.
I do not have Nginx or Apache installed yet.
I am trying to have first and Upstart Puma script developed first.
Running the command:

```
$ sudo start puma-manager
puma-manager start/running
```

gives me the impression that everything is ok while in reality the command

```
$ ps -ef | grep puma
```

returns nothing.
Digging more into the log file

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/puma-_home_deploy_tasks_current.log
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
[2889] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[2889] * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
[2889] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[2889] * Environment: development
[2889] * Process workers: 2
[2889] * Preloading application
[2889] ! Unable to load application: LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/home/deploy/tasks/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma)
LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile
  /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
  /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
  /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
```

Don't know how to fix this and move forward with the Puma settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I scrapped the AWS EC2 instance and recreate it using and Ubuntu 14.04 implementation which I upgraded to 16.04.
I followed strictly the guidance found here

```
http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-puma-capistrano-nginx-jungle-upstart/
```

and related links from the same blog.

Now Nginx and Puma are working properly together and my app runs perfectly here:

```
http://ec2-54-159-156-217.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
```

The only difference form the guidelines is that I kept the AWS RDS instance for the database.
I used RVM in the production server although I am using RBENV on my Mac.
I used ubuntu user (like root) for deployment since I am suspecting all the troubles I had were related to permissions and I did not know how to fix them.

Many errors encountered earlier trying to start properly Puma on socket and make it working with Nginx, especially not restarting after

```
cap production deploy
```

were related to generating the `secret` and putting this value in the appropiate file. For me it worked the best writing it in the `/etc/environment` file.

I also did changes in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in order to get `root` or `ubuntu` access through `ssh`. In this matter this link

```
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=86876
```

was very useful.